# Selecionar texto de um elemento HTML

Tags: javascript, html, string

Estou tentando copiar um texto de um elemento HTML, é um código que transforma as primeiras letras das palavras em maiúsculo (e os "da,da,dos" em minúsculo) e estou tentando implementar essa função de copiar automaticamente, porém não estou conseguindo selecionar o texto. Ignorem as gambiarras. Ainda sou iniciante.

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="NomeMaiusculo" placeholder="Nome">
    <input type="submit" id="n importa" onclick="escola()">

*/Esse h3 aqui/*

    <h3></h3>
    <button onclick="copiarTexto()">Copiar</button>
<script>

 function escola () {

  function titleize(text) {
    var loweredText = text.toLowerCase();
    var words = loweredText.split(" ");
    for (var a = 0; a < words.length; a++) {
        var w = words[a];

        var firstLetter = w[0];


        if( w.length > 2){ 
           w = firstLetter.toUpperCase() + w.slice(1);
        } else {
           w = firstLetter + w.slice(1);
        }

        words[a] = w;
    }
    return words.join(" ");

}
var alt = document.getElementById('NomeMaiusculo');
    var alt1 = alt.value;

//selecionei ele aqui

    var h3 = document.querySelector('h3')

var b1 = (titleize(alt1));                                    
var res = b1.replace("De,Da,Dos", "de,da,dos");
  h3.textContent = (titleize(res));

  function copiarTexto () {

//quero selecionar oque tem dentro dele,depois da função titleize

            h3.select();

            document.execCommand('copy');
            }
}
  </script>
```

Comment: Até respondo a sua duvida sobre copiar um texto dum elemento fraseado, mas refatore esse código pois quem for responder vai ser moralmente obrigado a tecer considerações sobre o estilo de codificação.

Comment: Que?, poderia me ajudar com isso?